# How can I have php artisan:migrate run a dynamic set of SQL scripts?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, database-migration

I have a laravel app which uses a database which is migrated by raw SQL scripts rather than php migrations.

For local development and testing, I would like to hook those scripts into `php artisan migrate`. My desired behavior is that every time someone runs `php artisan migrate`, laravel will gather up the scripts and run all the ones that have not run before.

One way to do this would be to create a php Migration file for every script, but I'm wondering if I can hook into the process which gathers the migration files to do this dynamically.

I tried registering my own instance of `Migrator` in `AppServiceProvider`, but this didn't seem to work.

Comment: You can try with creating a command using make:command. So you don't need to register it with AppServiceProvider. Then add your logic to run the script in the command file and register the command in the Kernel file.

Comment: I think you're probably best off creating a migration for each of your scripts and having Laravel run them (and keep track of which ones have been run). Migrations are perfectly capable of running raw SQL in `up()` and `down()` instead of using the Schema Builder. Personally, I'm not aware of any way to hook into the process, since it uses the filenames and batch numbers to track which migrations have and have not been run.

Answer (score 0):

- First, create a custom Artisan command that will handle the execution of your raw SQL scripts:

```
php artisan make:command RunSqlMigrations
```

- Place your SQL scripts in a specific directory and follow a naming convention that allows you to track which ones have been executed, such as including a timestamp or a version number in the file name.
- Use a table in your database to keep track of which scripts have been run. This is similar to how Laravel's migrations table works.
- In your custom command:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class RunSqlMigrations extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'migrate:sql';
    protected $description = 'Run raw SQL migrations';

    public function handle()
    {
        $sqlDirectory = database_path('sql_migrations');
        $files = File::allFiles($sqlDirectory);

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $filename = $file->getFilename();

            if ($this->alreadyRun($filename)) {
                $this->info("Skipping: {$filename}");
                continue;
            }

            try {
                DB::unprepared(File::get($file->getPathname()));
                $this->recordAsRun($filename);
                $this->info("Migrated: {$filename}");
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->error("Failed to migrate: {$filename}");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    protected function alreadyRun($filename)
    {
        return DB::table('sql_migrations')->where('filename', $filename)->exists();
    }

    protected function recordAsRun($filename)
    {
        DB::table('sql_migrations')->insert(['filename' => $filename, 'migrated_at' => now()]);
    }
}
```

- Register your new command in Console/Kernel.php so that it's available as an Artisan command.
- you can use it by running this command:

```
php artisan migrate:sql
```

- If you want to run your raw SQL migrations as part of the `php artisan migrate` command, you may extend the `MigrateCommand` or listen for a `MigrationsEnded` event (if available) and trigger your SQL migrations after the normal migrations have completed.

PS: I took these codes from my old project. You can modify it due to your needs.

Comment: This is making a custom command as opposed to hooking into php artisan migrate, right?